# How can I add a variable in place f a constant in javascript

Tags: javascript

var strSQLQuery = "SELECT App_Type FROM [APP_Type$] WHERE ToExec = 'YES'";
I want to have a variable in place of APP_Type.

Comment: This opens you to SQL injection attacks. Your database driver will likely have a way to run a parameterized query, such as `run("select app_type from ? where to_exec = ?", ["mytable", "yes"])`

Comment: See also: Little Bobby Tables https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
const tableName = 'Users';
const strSQLQuery = `SELECT App_Type FROM ${tableName} WHERE ToExec = 'YES'`;
```

...but as others point out, you should be *very* careful that whatever variable you plug in is trusted data, not user data. Your database library may also have safer ways to build a query *without* using a SQL string.